# compiling it++ with MingW blas & lapack cannot be found

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, msys

I'm trying to compile [IT++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/) library using MinGW/MSYS
I compiled `fftw` and `lapack` successfully and their lib files (`libfftw3.a`, `libfftw3.la`, `libblas.a`, `liblapack.a`) exists in `/mingw/lib`
But When I try to use cmake like this:

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
```

I get:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:192 (message):
  BLAS library not found.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:196 (message):
  LAPACK library not found.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:204 (message):
  You can still compile IT++ but the functionality will be reduced.
```

Why it cannot find the libraries?
How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Note:**
I have

```
%MINGW_HOME%\msys\1.0\bin;%MINGW_HOME%\bin;C:\dev\cmake-3.5.2-win32-x86\bin;%MINGW_HOME%\lib
```

in my `PATH` variable (where `%MINGW_HOME%` is `C:\dev\MinGW`)

Comment: Have you deleted your `CMakeCache.txt`?

Comment: Yes; and had no effect! But I finally was able to make it work using `-DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=/path/to/liblapack.a -DBLAS_LIBRARIES=/path/to/libblas.a `

Comment: Use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and add the paths there. That's the preferred way.

Comment: @usr1234567: I tried that too and it didn't worked!!!

Comment: Then you have to prune the path. Probably not including the `liblapack.a`, maybe even one more folder.